# Let predator eat the prey

Tags: c++

I´m doing an ant and bug game in c++.  I´m having some problems with the move function in bug.cpp named Bug::move()
My programes crash now after I added the if-s for finding if the ant was at the next grid, so it´s something wrong how the bug is eating the ant.
GetAt returns the organism at the given coordinates.
getType returns if it´s a bug or and
setAt sets the organism org at the position(x, y).

```
void Bug::move()
{

if(world->getAt(x, y + 1)->getType() == ANT)
{
    world->setAt(x, y, NULL);
    world->setAt(x, y + 1, this);
    breedTicks = 0;
    setMoved(true);
}
else if(world->getAt(x, y - 1)->getType() == ANT)
{
    world->setAt(x, y, NULL);
    world->setAt(x, y - 1, this);
    breedTicks = 0;
    setMoved(true);
}
else if(world->getAt(x - 1, y)->getType() == ANT)
{
    world->setAt(x, y, NULL);
    world->setAt(x - 1, y, this);
    breedTicks = 0;
    setMoved(true);
}
else if(world->getAt(x + 1, y)->getType() == ANT)
{
    world->setAt(x, y, NULL);
    world->setAt(x + 1, y, this);
    breedTicks = 0;
    setMoved(true);
}

else
{
    Move randomMove = world->randomMove();

    if((randomMove == UP) && (y < WORLDSIZE - 1) && (world->getAt(x, y + 1) == NULL))
    {   
        movesTo(x, y + 1);
    }
    if((randomMove == DOWN) && (y > 0) && (world->getAt(x, y - 1) == NULL))
    {
        movesTo(x, y - 1);
    }
    if((randomMove == LEFT) && (x > 0) && (world->getAt(x - 1, y) == NULL))
    {
        movesTo(x - 1, y);
    }
    if((randomMove == RIGHT) && (x < WORLDSIZE - 1) && (world->getAt(x + 1, y) == NULL))
    {
        movesTo(x + 1, y);
    }
}
breedTicks++;
}
```

Comment: What does `world->getAt(...)` / `world->setAt(...)` do with index out of bounds? Same for `Bug->movesTo(...)`.

Comment: Before home computers, my favourite preditor was premacs.

Comment: My main problem for now is how I look for if there is an ant, after I get that right, I´ll fix the code to eat the ant.

Comment: Can `world->getAt(...)` return a NULL?  I see that you pass a NULL for `world->setAt(...)`

Comment: I was trying to remove the ant :)  but I´ll fix that code if I can figure out the if line

Comment: What a (view) success ! Lesson learned: a good title makes everything...

Answer (score 0):

If you still need an answer..

You need to first check if the grid has NULL in the spot or not. You can do that like so:

```
 if(world->getAt(x, y+1) != NULL && world->getAt(x, y+1)->getType() == ANT) 
 {
   world->setAt(x, y, NULL);
   world->setAt(x - 1, y, this);
   breedTicks = 0;
   setMoved(true);
 }
```

that way you wont get the NULL pointer reference and the program crashes on you.